# PHP - Coneixon SFTP no logra realizarse

Tags: php, linux, ssh, ftp, ssl

Estoy conectando a un servidot FTP Seguro, pero a la hora de EXTRAER los archivos, no me permite :(

El siguiente codigo tiene las siguientes constantes:

- SSL_PORT = El puerto del servidor SSL, que generalmente es 22.
- SSL_SERVER = Booleando true o false, para saber si usa o no conexion segura.
- SSL_PORT = El puerto del FTP
- FTP_USER = usuario del ftp
- FTP_USER_PASS = password del ftp
- FTP_SERVER = Nombre de dominio del FTP.

  ```
    private function getStream($fileName, $folder) {
    if( self::SSL_SERVER ) {
        echo "\n\n";
        echo "\nPort: ". self::SSL_PORT;
        echo "\nCarpeta: ". $folder;
        echo "\nArchivo: ". $fileName;
        echo "\n\n";
        if( !($socket= ssh2_connect(self::FTP_SERVER, self::SSL_PORT)) )
            echo "\n[ERROR-FTP] Problemas para conectar al FTP Seguro..";
        else {
            echo "\nSSH2_Connect - OK..";
            if( !(ssh2_auth_password($socket, self::FTP_USER, self::FTP_USER_PASS)) )
                echo "\n[ERROR-FTP] Problemas para autentificarse al FTP Seguro..";
            else {
                echo "\nSSH2_AUTH_PASSWORD - OK..";
                if( !($sFtp= ssh2_sftp($socket)) )
                    echo "\n[ERROR-FTP] Problemas para abrir el FTP Seguro..";
                else {
                    echo "\nSSH2_SFTP - OK..";
                    $stream = fopen("ssh2.sftp://$sFtp/$fileName", "r");
                    echo "\nStream abierto...";
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        $stream = fopen("ftp://".self::FTP_USER.":".self::FTP_USER_PASS."@".self::FTP_SERVER."/".$this->COMPANY_FOLDER."/$folder/$fileName", "r");
    }

    if ($stream == false) { fclose($stream); return null; }

    echo "\nLeyendo stream..";
    // if( self::SSL_SERVER ) {
    //     $result= fread($stream, filesize("ssh2.sftp://$sFtp/$fileName"));
    // }
    // else {
        $result = stream_get_contents($stream);
    // }
    echo "\nStream leido..";
    fclose($stream);
    return $result;
  ```

  }

El codigo se queda ejecutando en la llamada a **ssh2_connect** y despues de unos minutos indica el error de *[ERROR-FTP] Problemas para conectar al FTP Seguro..*.

Ya verifique los datos de USUARIO y CLAVE, y si son correcto, el FTP me conecta con exito usando FileZilla...

Que puedo hacer? por donde puedo buscarle mas?

--- UPDATE  03/12/2024, 14:31
Les coloco aca la salida del error en php:

> PHP Warning:  ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to ftp2.miempresa.com on
> port 22 in /app/libs/ftp_manager.php on line 241 PHP Warning:
> ssh2_connect(): Unable to connect to ftp2.ups.com in
> /app/libs/ftp_manager.php on line 241

La linea 241 que se menciona, es la llamada a **ssh2_connect()**

Comment: con la ip funciona?

Comment: @aloMalbarez acabo de hacer la prueba de conectar a la IP en vez del dominio, y hace lo mismo :(.... El FTP al que intento conectar es: ftp2.ups.com

Comment: `$ sftp -vvv ftp2.ups.com` te da verbose de como va la negociación. puede que no sea sftp sino ftps ( o que haya que authorizar el ip si el host es diferente )

Comment: @aloMalbarez ya lo resolvi, pero no logre hacerlo con el metodo que esta publicado en todas partes, opte por otra opcion, ya agrege respuesta de como lo resolvi...

Answer (score 1):

Pues no logre resolver con la forma de ssh2_connect(), sino con esta forma:

```
$socket = ftp_ssl_connect(self::FTP_SERVER)
$loginResult = ftp_login($socket, self::FTP_USER, self::FTP_USER_PASS);
ftp_set_option($socket, FTP_USEPASVADDRESS, false);
ftp_pasv($socket, true);
$tempFile = fopen('/tmp/tmp.txt', 'w');
ftp_fget($socket, $tempFile, $folder."/".$fileName, FTP_ASCII); // leemos del FTP
```

Comment: cla, el protocolo es [`ftpS`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS) en vez de [`sFTP`](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol)